# didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo not working when calling

Tags: swift

I tried this code to update the picture, but this function wasn't called.

```
extension ChildDetailEditVC: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as! UIImage
        imageChild.image = chosenImage
        dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: How is shown/created the `UIImagePickerController` ? DId you set the instance of `ChildDetailEditVC` as `delegate`?

Comment: var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController() and called this in viewDidLoad imagePicker.delegate = self

Comment: Can you share the snippet where you have instantiated the `UIImagePickerController()` ?

Comment: var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController() I added in the Root view controller and in ChildDetailEditVC I'm using this imagePicker. Also I called the imagePicker.delegate = self in viewDidLoad(). But when I run the app imagePickerControllerDidCancel and didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo not working

Comment: In `viewDidLoad()` of `ChildDetailEditVC`? Also, could you show you are retrieving the `imagePicker` from "Root view controller"? I'm wondering if you aren't using a new instance...

Comment: import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON
import Alamofire

class ChildDetailEditVC: RootVC  {                                                                                                                                                                       @IBOutlet weak var imageChild: BorderRoundImage!                                                                   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        SetupUI()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
    }

Comment: Since they are named `Root` & `ChildDetailEdit`, I thought about child, not inherited VC. Is `ChildDetailEditVC` calling the present on imagepicker? Could you edit your question with that new code, to make it clearer?

Comment: Please add your UIImagePickerController code and make sure that you assign picker.delegate = self.